# ng test returns '0 tests completed'

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I updated my workspace to Angular 6 recently, and I'm currently working on updating the scripts in package.json. On running the command
 `ng test retail --source-map=false` 
the test returns **0 Tests Completed** in the Summary. I can't seem to figure out where I've missed any inclusions. In tsconfig.json, I have

```
"include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.spec.shallow.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
```

I've included 
`mime: { 'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']}` and `require('karma-requirejs')` 
in my karma.conf.js file, but nothing seems to work. I tried changing the browser to Firefox from Chrome, but to no avail. 
My angular.json file has three projects with 
`"tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"` 
configured for all three.

- > rxjs                              6.1.0
- > typescript                        2.7.2
- > Angular CLI:                      6.0.1
- > Node:                             9.4.0
- > karma                             1.7.0

> .. 69% building modules 1214/1229 modules 15 active ….\lib\worker.js(node:58392) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.apply is deprecated. Call apply on the plugin directly instead ..
>
> Chrome 66.0.3359 (Windows 10.0.0) LOG: 'pdl:digital-data:Initializing  digitalDataObj' 
>   Chrome 66.0.3359 (Windows 10.0.0) LOG: 'pdl:digital-data:Initializing digitalDataObj'
>
> Finished in 0.006 secs / 0 secs @ 17:01:58 GMT+0530 (India Standard
>   Time)
>
> SUMMARY:
>   √ 0 tests completed 
>   18 05 2018 17:01:58.729:DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exiting.
>   18 05 2018 17:01:58.729:DEBUG [launcher]:
>   Disconnecting all browsers ..

Comment: If you had tests before and it outputs that, it means you have errors in your tests. In this case, the console or your browser would notify you about that. Could you please post the console output of the test command ?

Comment: I've updated the question with a snapshot. Could you confirm if the problem is with `./reb-webworker\lib\worker.js` ?

Comment: I don't have access to images. Could you post the error in plain text please ?

Comment: As a formatted edit in your question please ...

Comment: I updated the query with the console output.